# A word used to describe someone who loves to be photographed

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns, epithet-requests

I am trying to figure out if there is a word to describe a person who loves to be photographed.

Comment: Without an indication of what you have already considered or where you have already looked for such a word, we don't know where to start. Please edit your question to describe your prior thought and research.

Comment: How about *a willing subject*?

Comment: More information, please. For example, is the person in question a child, a woman or a man? Is the *poser* a professional model or a family member? It would be at least a little clearer and more helpful for the community.

Comment: This question probably belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) because it is about communicating in everyday English, and is not about the academic study of English Language.

Comment: What is unclear or 'too broad' about it?

Comment: You can see the phrase `photo hound` is used to desribe this: http://jakkic669hsb.blogspot.com/2013/02/photo-hound.html

Comment: @Matt, no, it emphatically does *not* belong on ELL just because it's "about communicating in everyday English", whatever that means. (Is that code for "I don't like simple questions"?) This question has nothing to do with *learning* English, therefore it does not belong on ELL.

Comment: @Marthaª: Sure it's about Learning English. It's about learning how "to describe a person who loves to be photographed" in English, and it's off topic on ELU because "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered."

Comment: "*Poseophile*"? Neologism: loves posing for pictures.

Comment: @Kris How does one of those differ from a *poser* or a *poseur*?

Comment: By all rights, a person who flutters about, trying to be constantly in camera range and to get into as many photographs as possible ought to be called a _flash moth_.

Comment: @WS2 Those words have alternate meanings and usage.

Answer (score 7):

Poser - you can use both meanings.

#1 - a person who acts in an affected manner in order to impress others.

#2 - a person posing for a picture

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? The OP may not understand what "both meanings" are.

Comment: Isn't 'poser' used in a negative manner?

Comment: The connotations differ.  When my 3-year-old sees a camera he is definitely a little poser - in a good way.

Comment: Usually when a word has multiple meanings you pick one of them. Are there some example sentences you can find somewhere where `poser` is used to mean this?

Comment: @user814064 You want examples of all the ways poser could be used?

Comment: Maybe this will make it clear. http://www.searchquotes.com/search/Poser/

Comment: For example I'm assuming that the meaning here is not Obama's love of being photographed. You can find millions of quotes where poser is used like this: http://www.godlikeproductions.com/forum1/message1079215/pg1 OBAMA IS A POSER, LIAR AND FAILURE AT EVEYTHING HE TOUCHES

Comment: Everyone who sits for a snap (*poser*) is **not** "a person who loves to be photographed"

Answer (score 6):

You could use *camwhore*, but it has negative connotations of craving attention.

"The term "[camwhore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camgirl)" is also used to refer to individuals who post pictures or videos of themselves on the Internet to gain attention. The term disparages those who post pictures of themselves at inappropriate times or places and usually implies self-absorption. This second usage of the term, deriding vanity and histrionics, is overtaking the prior more intuitive definition."

If you want to be a bit more positive, plain old *model* might work

Answer (score 3):

you can call them ***lens hog*** or a ***camera hog***

from the sense of gluttony conveyed by [*hog*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hog?s=t)

I have heard them used often. Although I have used *camera whore* as well, I admit it can be derogatory when used for strangers.

Another term I have encountered before and considered not to be a particularly inventive one is ***lensfucker*** - here's the definition from urban dictionary:

> Somebody who loves the camera lens almost as much as they love themselves and the way they look.

1. *"Amy is such a Lensfucker. Just look at her scene picture on myspace. Camera Whore."*
2. *David and Victoria Beckham are a pair of lensfuckers.*

Answer (score 2):

**Photo freak** refers to someone who loves to take pictures of everything he does, and could also be used in this case.

Comment: You need to add support for such authoritative-sounding statements. Here is a quote from someone saying your _opinion_ is **wrong**:   Re: Photo freak.
Quote Originally Posted by david11...I thought that 'photo freak', in general, means people who like to have there their photographs taken.>> **moderator** (Eng. teacher):
OK. You asked what it means. I gave you two possible meanings. You then asked if it can also mean someone who likes to pose for photos. I said no. I'm not sure what other information I can give you. ( http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/167078-photo-freak-2.html )

Comment: Yes, your are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

***[A narcisist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/narcisist)*** is a person who admires and is obsessed with their image. A narcissistic personality has a need for admiration, affirmation and gratification from others. This can also be manifested in their quest to achieve physical perfection; as they tend to think quite highly of themselves they will never hesitate to have their photo taken.

> The term narcissism comes from the Greek myth of Narcissus, a handsome
>   Greek youth who rejected the desperate advances of the nymph Echo.
>   These advances eventually led Narcissus to fall in love with his own
>   reflection in a pool of water. Unable to consummate his love,
>   Narcissus "lay gazing enraptured into the pool, hour after hour," and
>   finally changed into a flower that bears his name, the narcissus

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. In Swedish the term used is "linslus" composed of "lins" (lens) and "lus" (louse). Very much like the term shutter bug, but shutter bug is used for the person behind the camera.

Answer (score 0):

*Camera ham*: "[a very over-enthusiastic model for the camera, loves the attention, and loves to be photographed.](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_a_camera_hog_and_a_camera_ham)"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ***camera loving*** might be used for both the people who like being photographed and for those who like taking photographs.

Comment: I've converted the rhetorical question to an answer to the question asked at the top of the page. Feel free to make it more definite. It's **always** best to give positive answers, not tentative ones.